# Installation of python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, installation, kivy

I have installed Python 3.4 on my windows 7 64bit system and it runs OK with eclipse. But I am trying to install kivy or pyQT and I get a message that Python 3.4 is not installed on my system. I am totally new to python and all its modules. What can I do to correct this problem? I need a GUI but I think that first I need to make sure that Python is properly install. I hope this questionis not too basic and that I am asking on the right place.

Comment: How are you trying to install kivy or pyQT? Try installing them using pip, found in the Python34\Scripts\ folder.

Comment: @Pulimon I have trird what you suggested installing kivy and I get and error "ImportError: No module named "Cython"" Then when I try to install Cython I get many warning and "error: Setup script exited with error: unable to find  vcvarsall.bat"

Comment: Then when I try to install pyQt I get "Coukld not find any dowloads that satisfy the requirement pyQt

Comment: That's because there aren't any suitable downloads on pipy. Try http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ for all scientific python packages on windows!

Comment: Problem with this question is that you do not give enough information (how exactly do you try to install) and that it is not specific enough (one question for kivy and one for pyqt) and that you do not say what exactly goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help with PyQT, and possibly this should have been two separate questions. But for Kivy the easiest way to get started is to download the portable package, which includes Python, Kivy, and all the dependencies compiled and ready to go. You can read the instructions for using the portable package here: http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html

If you really want to install Kivy yourself into an existing Python install, you can follow these instructions instead: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Using-Kivy-with-an-existing-Python-installation-on-Windows-%2864-or-32-bit%29

Finally, to set up your IDE for use with the Kivy portable package (if necessary): https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE%27s

Oh, one last caveat: we are working on Python 3 support, and Kivy will run perfectly in Python 3, but packaging is another matter. There are working packaging solutions for Windows apps using Python 3, but if you intend to deploy your app to Android or iOS you currently must use Python 2.

Comment: thanks for the information, I tried installing the portable version without any luck. I get a message that says "Python 3.4 required, which was not found in the registry. I had already added the path to the registry . I have installed the 2.7 version and I am up and running.